# How can I get elastic search to return results inside angle brackets?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, analyzer

I'm new to elastic search.  I'm trying to fix our search so that it will allow users to search on content within html tags.  Currently, we're using a whitespace tokenizer because we need it to return results on hyphenated names. Consequently, `aname123-suffix project` is indexed as `["aname123-suffix", "project"]` and a user search for `"aname123-*"` returns the correct results.

My problem arises because we also want to be able to search on content within html tags.  So, for example for a project called `<aname123>-suffix project`, we'd like to be able to enter the search term `<aname123>-*` and get back the correct results.

The index has the correct tokens for a whitespace tokenizer, namely `["<aname123>-suffix", "project"]` but when my search string is `"\<aname123\>\-suffix"` or `"\\<aname123\\>\\-suffix"` elastic search returns no results.

I think the solution lies either in

1. modifying the search string so that elastic search returns `<aname123>-suffix` when I ask for it; or
2. being able to index the content within the tag separately from the whitespace tokens, i.e. `["<aname123>-suffix", "project", "aname123", "suffix"]`

So far I've been approaching it by changing the indexing, but I have not yet succeeded. A standard tokenizer will allow search results for content within tags, but it fails to return search results for `aname123-*`. Currently my analyzer settings look like this:

```
{  "analysis":
         { "analyzer":
              { "my_whitespace_analyzer" :
                  {"type": "custom"
                        {"tokenizer": "whitespace},
                        {"filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "stop"]}
                  }
              },
              { "my_tag_analyzer":
                  {"type": "custom"
                        {"tokenizer": "standard"},
                        {"filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "stop"]}
                   }
               }
           }
 }
```

I can create a custom char filter that strips out the < and the >, so my index contains `aname123`; but for some reason elastic search still does not return correct results when searching on `<aname123>*`.  However, when I use instead a standard analyzer, the index contains `aname123` *and* it returns the expected results for `<aname123>*` ... What is so special about angle brackets in elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the html_strip character filter:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html

An example from one of the elasticsearch developers is here:

https://gist.github.com/clintongormley/780895

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that but it strips out content within the tags as well as the angle brackets.  I want to keep the content within the tags.  `<atag>` should index to `atag`...

Comment: but that made me think... I should be able to use a char filter that replaces `<` and `>` with nothing...

Comment: I haven't looked too closely into it, but my understanding is that that is what it does, based on the gist example I linked

Comment: In the linked example, the request that used a "standard" analyzer returned the content within the tags, but the requests that used the custom analyzers  with html_strip took it away.